# ReactiveCommand not respecting canExecute

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Perhaps I'm missing something, however I can't get ReactiveCommand to prevent execution based on the canExecute observable.

Below is the simplest example I can conjure. I would expect the command to never fire, however it is.

What am I missing?

```
void Main()
{
    var canExecute = Observable.Return(false);
    var myCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canExecute, m => functions.doAllThings(m));

    myCommand.Subscribe(x=>"executing".Dump());

    myCommand.Execute("Tom"); // This fires the command. I would have expected it to block
}

static class functions
{
    public static Task doAllThings(object message)
    {
        var result = Task.Run(() =>{
                    "running task...".Dump();
                    return "hello " + (string)message;});

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note - This is question is kind of a 'fork' from [Executing a command from another command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25591175/494635). I believe that this is more the core issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by-design. ReactiveUI doesn't stop you from explicitly calling `Execute` / `ExecuteAsync`, and trusts that You Know What You're Doing™

Comment: Aaah - thanks Paul. That's not what I would have expected. I have to admit that I'm still far from knowing what I'm doing... but day by day I'm learning :-)

Comment: The same applies to your own ICommand implementations. Normally nobody does something like if(!CanExecute(null) return; within the Execute method. You expect only to be called when you can execute.

Comment: @0xBADF00D I have to be honest, this behavior caught me off guard.  The same _does not_ apply to my own `ICommand` implementation.  I don't see much value in encapsulating the `CanExecute` and `Excute` behavior into an `ICommand` object if the two methods operate completely independent of each other.  If I want that behavior then I may as well just drop the two methods into my ViewModel and leave out the unnecessary abstraction.  I use a command precisely because I do not trust the caller to not do something stupid.

Comment: Can I force command to queue Execute calls? Or just create observable with parameters and subscribe to it?